# Self employed, I'm applying for a UK visa from Ghana

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My business registered in April 2022. I use my savings account for my savings.my father will sponsor my trip. Do I have the opportunity to be granted UK visitors visa since I don't have business bank account??

Comment: Do you have other ties to Ghana? Being self employed and being sponsored for your trip is not the best ground to expect a visa. Having a business account is not needed but being able to show your financial status is. (Statements of your savings account does help, but maybe not enough.)

Comment: Yes I have documented land

Comment: What was your occupation before you set up your business?  What is your travel history? What is the purpose of your proposed visit to the UK and how long do you plan to stay? Owning land might help but isn’t as compelling a reason to return as say a job or family dependents

Comment: I graduated from the university in 2016 finish my service in 2017. I taught under contract from 2018 - 2021. I traveled from Ghana to Burkina Faso in 2017. I'm attending my sister's graduation in UK. I'm planning to stay for 5 days

Comment: Your chances look slim IMHO but the only way to find out is to apply.